# Symfony JavaScript asset problems (double project name)

Tags: javascript, php, apache, symfony

I'm trying to deploy my `Symfony Projects`. My Problem is that on the deployment server all links for the JavaScript files are broken.

On my development server the links look like : `/js/token.js`

On my production server the links look like: `/projectname/projectname/js/token.js.`

I already cleared the cache and dumped all assets.

Does somebody know how to fix it or where to look?

Bruno

p.s.:

```
{% javascripts '@Bundle/Resources/public/js/javascriptfile.js'%}
  <script type='text/javascript' src="{{ asset( asset_url ) }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

Comment: It may be related to the web server virtual host root path. Have you configured it to e.g /var/www/html/project/web ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [documentation about Assetic](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#including-javascript-files),

Example from that page:

```
{% javascripts '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/*' %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

So, I think it should work if you change `{{ asset( asset_url ) }}` to `{{ asset_url }}`

Comment: still got the problem with the double projectname

Comment: @Bruno I think you should provide some more information about what you did... How did you configure, you dumped them or not, so on..

Comment: the problem is i don't really know which part of the application causes the problem so i don't know which kind of information are important ...

Answer (score 0):

Add `output` option:

```
{% javascripts '@Bundle/Resources/public/js/javascriptfile.js'
    output='js/javascriptfile.js' %}
    <script type='text/javascript' src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```